# handling null values on select query mysql

Tags: mysql, null

table stockholders

```
stockholder_id    election_id    user_id    
1                 1              1                          
2                 1              2          
3                 2              3
```

table users

```
user_id           user_type
1                 1
2                 1
3                 1
4                 1
5                 1
```

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tbl_users
left join tbl_stockholders
    on tbl_stockholders.user_id = tbl_users.user_id
where 
    user_type=1 
    and stockholders.user_id is null 
    and election_id <> 1
```

i want to search election_id not equal to 1 and user type equal to 1

```
stockholder_id    election_id    user_id      user_type
3                 2                 3            1         
null              null              4            1
null              null              5            1
```

this is an update

sorry my problem should be excluding the tbl_stockholders from the tbl_users with the parameter election_id.. because a problem exist when i have a duplicate user_id

table stockholders

```
stockholder_id    election_id    user_id    
1                 1              1                          
2                 1              2          
3                 2              3   
4                 1              3
```

in the previous answer this is the result when election_id<>2

```
stockholder_id    election_id    user_id      user_type
3                 1                 3            1         
null              null              4            1
null              null              5            1
```

this must be

```
stockholder_id    election_id    user_id      user_type      
null              null              4            1
null              null              5            1
```

this is my current not working code

select * from tbl_users
where not exists (select * from tbl_stockholders where election_id <> 2)

Comment: Why do you have the predicate `tbl_stockholders.user_id is null` in your query?  Especially since `tbl_stockholders` is on the left of your `left join`?

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: tbl_users.user_id is null to exclude the user in the tbl_stockholders sorry is tbl_users not tbl_stockholders @eggyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN stockholders s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE u.user_type = 1 AND (s.election_id <> 1 OR s.election_id IS NULL)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41b8c/1).

Comment: SELECT * FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN stockholders s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
    WHERE u.user_type = 1 AND (s.election_id <> 1 OR s.election_id IS NULL)

Comment: thanks.. thats works.. just changing election_id=2 to election_id<>1

Comment: That is correct: The condition should be `<> 1` rather than `= 2`. Due to the low amount of data the results matched :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you should do:
`select 
    * 
from 
    tbl_stockholders
left join tbl_users 
    on tbl_users.user_id = tbl_stockholders.user_id
where 
    (user_type=1 
    and election_id <> 1)`
I don't think you intend to select null user_ids. Also that would invalidate the join i.e you are saying joined the two tables based user_id but select null user_id from the first table.

Comment: hmm.. tbl_stockholders is the selection of users on tbl_users , then i want to search a users does not exist in tbl_stockholders. and not equal election_id ,, sorry for my english i cant explain it clearly.. sorry